# What are some libraries for doing a 3d orbiter with <canvas>?

Tags: canvas, webgl

I'm looking to do a 3-d orbiter, thus, I obviously need perspective views, camera movement, etc.  I also need to be able to apply textures to the geometry.  Given the complexity, I don't see this happening in anything other than `<canvas>` or flash.

As I understand it, `<canvas>` is limited to 2d, but you can do all of the 3d work with JS and simply output the 2d projection into the canvas.  My understanding stops right about there, and figuring all of this out seems rather complicated.

**Question #1:** What 3d graphics libraries are out there that offer the basic features that I need (3d->2d perspective projections, textures, animation of the camera, and fluid user input that pans, zooms, tilts, dollies, etc. the camera)?

**Question #2:** Out of the non-proprietary libraries that offer this type of functionality that I've been able to find on my own (three.js and C3DL,) they all appear to require webGL.  Is webGL pretty much required for this type of thing, or is support for `<canvas>` sufficient?  If webGL isn't required, is there any reason to use it if I'm not making anything that would bog down the CPU?

Note: I'm going to go ahead and try to learn three.js to get this done unless someone advises otherwise.

Comment: What is a 3D orbiter? Sounds like fun.

Comment: @LarsH Basically a series of navigational controls, allowing the user to zoom, truck/dolly, rotate about a focal point, etc. with the camera -- features that are common for 3d-modelling packages such as 3DSMax, Maya, etc.  See the solarcoordinates.com link below to see my laggy, but mostly working first attempt at it.

Comment: so, not necessarily a spacecraft simulation? I saw your first attempt, which looks very successful so far, but was wondering what would be shown at the focal point. The solar system?

Comment: @LarsH You can do all sorts of things with an engine like this.  See, for example, http://mrdoob.github.com/three.js/examples/webgl_materials_cars.html and http://mrdoob.github.com/three.js/examples/webgl_geometry_large_mesh.html .  They have inferior navigation of the camera, but nonetheless, there's a lot of potential to make cool stuff -- game engines, you name it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, Canvas is in no way "limited" to 2D. There is a 2D context and if you really want you can make 3D scenes with it (see below). As you say, there is additionally the WebGL context for 3D rendering that uses a different spec.

To answer #2, WebGL is in no way a requirement. For instance this library projects 3D using only the 2D canvas context:

http://arc.id.au/Canvas3DGraphics.html

There are also several examples of projective texturing/rotating objects, such as:

http://acko.net/files/projective/index.html

To answer #1, there is the library linked above, but its really the only one I've seen that uses the 2D context.

Comment: Hello, Simon.  After looking into the matter, I found that there were examples made for three.js that used normal canvas capabilities and also WebGL.  I've made some modifications to a normal canvas three.js example and have come up with this: http://mrdoob.com/projects/voxels/#A/aXYShShaheYeYkShShaieSiSfaifShShaheYhShShaieShShaheYhafiYhaehShYhYhaicShShShShYhYhSeYfSeYhaXiafhShahfahhaafShYiSfaffachShaniYfYiafhShShShYfamcYfYfShShYhYhShShYfYfYa (I added the ability to zoom with the mousewheel and also ctrl+click&drag.  Next up on the docket is "trucking" or "strafing" the camera.)

Comment: Sorry... that was the wrong link.  Here's my modification: http://www.solarcoordinates.com/three/voxels.html#A/aXYShShaheYeYkShShaieSiSfaifShShaheYhShShaieShShaheYhafiYhaehShYhYhaicShShShShYhYhSeYfSeYhaXiafhShahfahhaafShYiSfaffachShaniYfYiafhShShShYfamcYfYfShShYhYhShShYfYfYa